# Retrieving news feed list in SharePoint Hosted Apps leads to Forbidden Error(403)

Tags: sharepoint-online, newsfeed

I am developing news feed as an app part in SharePoint Online. This is my code to get social feed in my timeline using REST API.

```
 function getTimeline() {

            $.ajax({
                method: 'GET',
                url:hostweburl + "/_api/social.feed/my/timelinefeed",
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data)
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert("GET error:\n" + xhr.status + "\n" + thrownError);
                }
            });
}
```

When I am access this URL directly in browser it successfully gets the list items but this code gets forbidden error(403).

[image]

I searched about this issue and tried of using executor with the same error.And the another problem is when deploying the app when I give News Feed (Social) permission level to Read or anything, trusting the app(trust it) results in error.Anyone help me on this.

**UPDATE:**
   I have tried the answer by @gautham and I think permission level issue is resolved but when accessing URL(appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/social.feed/my/timelinefeed?@target='" + hostweburl + "'") leads to error(Resource not found)

[image]

Help me to get out of this..

Comment: You put both 2013 and sharepoint-online tags. Is that Online or on-premise?

Comment: Sharepoint Online

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide correct permission to read/write data from social feed.

In the `AppManifest.xml`, provide the permission as below and then you will be able to read/write data from social feed.

[image]

Try it with sp request executor js as below:

```
'use strict';
    var hostweburl;
    var appweburl;
    // Load the required SharePoint libraries.
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Get the URI decoded URLs.
        hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));

        // Resources are in URLs in the form:
        // web_url/_layouts/15/resource
        var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";
        // Load the js file and continue to load the page with information about the list items.
        // SP.RequestExecutor.js to make cross-domain requests
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", getTimelineItems);
    });
    // Utilities
    // Retrieve a query string value.
    // For production purposes you may want to use a library to handle the query string.
    function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
        var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
        for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
            var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
            if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve) return singleParam[1];
        }
    }    
    //Retrieve all of the list items
    function getTimelineItems() {
        var executor;
        // Initialize the RequestExecutor with the app web URL.
        executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
        executor.executeAsync({
            url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/social.feed/my/timelinefeed?@target='" + hostweburl + "'",
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
            },
            success: getListItemsSuccessHandler,
            error: getListItemsErrorHandler
        });
    }
    //Populate the selectListItems control after retrieving all of the list items.
    function getListItemsSuccessHandler(data) {
        console.log(data)
    }
    function getListItemsErrorHandler(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
        console.log("Could not get list items: " + errorMessage);
    }
```

Since its a SharePoint hosted addin, you can also try the below code:

```
function getTimeline() {

            $.ajax({
                method: 'GET',
                url: "https://sitecollectionurl/_api/social.feed/my/timelinefeed",
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data)
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert("GET error:\n" + xhr.status + "\n" + thrownError);
                }
            });
}
```

Another code, similar to that used in MSDN:

```
var feedManagerEndpoint;  

// Get the SPAppWebUrl parameter from the query string and build  
// the feed manager endpoint.  

$(document).ready(function () {  
    var appweburl;  
    var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");  
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {  
        var param = params[i].split("=");  
        if (param[0] === "SPAppWebUrl") appweburl = param[1];  
    }  
    feedManagerEndpoint = decodeURIComponent(appweburl)+ "/_api/social.feed/my/timelinefeed";  
    getMyFeed();  
});  


// Get the current user's feed by using the   
// "<app web URL>/_api/social.feed/my/timelinefeed" endpoint.  

function getMyFeed() {  
    $.ajax( {  
        url: feedManagerEndpoint ,  
        headers: {   
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"  
        },  
        success: feedRetrieved,  
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {   
            alert("GET error:\n" + xhr.status + "\n" + thrownError);  
        }  
    });      
}  

// Parse the JSON data and iterate through the feed.  

function feedRetrieved(data) {  
    console.log(data);
}
```

Also, try with below permission level:

[image]

Comment: Given the Permission Level but after giving the permission, trusting app leads to error and also the same permission error results for retrieving feed lists

Comment: What's the error? Same as current error or different?

Comment: Trusting the app leads to error(Something went wrong) and same error for retrieving feed list

Comment: Can try creating a new app with above permission and then trying your code ?  Also try with the updated code i posted

Comment: ok.. I will try with above code

Comment: Hi @Gautam, I have tried your code and i think permission level issue is resolved but it doesn't get me the feed lists. It gives me Error(404 not found): Cannot find resource for the request social.feed

Comment: hi @Kumaraguru, did you try the second code ?

Comment: Yep....that again leads to 403 forbidden error

Comment: @Kumaraguru - can you try the 3rd one with updated permissions ?

Comment: But the social feed of your last updated code is taking from app web but i want the social feed of host web..Also I have already set the permissions to the above you mentioned